# How to send what ever list of DTOs are ready from(spring-boot) as a backend to the front(angular-12)?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have long list from Execution entity and after some process fill related ExecutionDto, the DTO is like this,

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExecutionDto {

    private long OrgUnitId;
    private long countsDone;
    private long countsShouldBe;
    private float progressPercentage;
    private double countsIndicator;
    private String OrgUnitDisplayName;

}
```

the method that processes Execution return list of ExecutionDto is like this,

```
public List<ExecutionDTO> processExecutions(){
// some proccess and return list of ExecutionDto
return listOfExecutions;

}
```

I don't want to use pagination and send what ever data is ready to the front and not wait the completed list, How can I do this?
and my web rest method is like this,

```
  @GetMapping("/executions/procces")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ExecutionDTO>> proccesedExecutions(){
    // get list of ExecutionDtos from related service 
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(executionDTOs);
    }
```

I expect gradually list to complete but front wait until back-end completed list, it takes a lot of time to complete the list of ExecutionDtos,

Comment: http is one response per one request. That said, you can probably choose to not close/commit the stream until you get the complete list and keep writing to the response body stream and close it once its done. I am not sure, with spring you will get such fine level controls

Answer (score 0):

To stream a list you should use WebFlux and return something like `Flux<List<ExecutionDTO>>`.

You'll need a reactive data store though to realistically stream results as the database returns them (e.g. MongoDB).

Comment: what is the point of using Flux in this case if you return Flux<List<T>> ? Then you should return Flux<T>

Comment: you mean if I use just Flux and add WebFlux as a dependency  my front doesn't wait until completed list?

Comment: A Flux can return a `MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE`, and the client can subscribe to the server sent events in the stream.

See an example at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events